# Spring. Accessing config variable in Thymeleaf.

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm in the process of trying to pass a configuration variable in Spring to a Thmyleaf template. I've loaded the variable from the Configuration file successfully with an annotation value and can output it via System.out. I'm just having trouble rendering it in my template.

application.yaml

```
acmeUrl:
   url:         https://www.acme.com
```

My Controller

```
   @Value("${acmeUrl.url}")
   private String acmeUrl;

   //grab from annotation and pass to the view
   modelView.addObject( "acmeUrl", this.acmeUrl );
```

My Thmeleaf template:

```
<span th:text="${acmeUrl}" />
```

The above works. But when I try a conditional check against a return querystring param, I get nothing back.

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" th:value="${param.return != null ? param.return[0] : acmeUrl }" />
```

Does my inline IF look correct here? Pretty sure that it is the culprit, but not sure if I need to change my formatting to get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-expressions

According to this, the proper syntax would be:
th:value="${param.return != null} ? {param.return[0]} : {acmeUrl}"